# What is this thing in my dishwasher?

Tags: dishwasher

What is this part in my dishwasher? It is not shown anywhere in the manual.  The brand is Electrolux.

[image: What is this?]

Comment: It's probably a float switch, I don't have any knowledge about your particular dishwasher tho.

Comment: That is definitely the float switch.

Comment: Thanks - I was having a drainage problem and wasn't sure it that had anything to do it. Based on the answers I would say it doesn't.

Comment: Looks like a float switch to me+

Answer (score 2):

According to many unofficial manuals, it is a salt container.

[image: os:http://rudn.nodevice.com/preview/big/123/123177-4.jpg]
[image: os:http://rudn.nodevice.com/preview/big/123/123158-4.jpg]

Comment: I see salt container in the prints you provided but have only ever known these to be a water level safety or float switch. Because of that will + to reverse the - .

Comment: I've never heard of putting salt in a dishwasher.

Comment: @DA01, you'd only do it if the unit has a water softener.  http://www.finishdishwashing.com/news-and-offers/dishwashing-articles/products/effectiveness-dishwasher-salt/